# Windows 8 install problems on HP Pavilion TouchSmart 23-f221ea All-in-One Desktop PC

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, sata, diskpart

I'm attempting a fresh Windows 8 install on completely brand new SATA hard drive, purchased yesterday and with the official Recovery Disks that were sent to me by HP.  I think I may have inadvertently damaged the last new Hard Drive as it started throwing up a lot of 'disk fail' errors.

I expected this to be a straight forward affair this time, but I was hit with the following message during the Recovery process: "Windows could not restore your computer using the factory image".

I followed this guy's advice: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-Systems-and-Recovery/Recovery-Manager-could-not-restore-computer-using-factory/m-p/1789727#M56805 and created a Windows 8 (though it may actually be 8.1) iso disk.

I started over with the iso disk, and followed the on-screen prompts until I was asked to select the install location. I selected the one and only 1TB drive displayed, but after almost 30 minutes, the installer said "Windows is unable to install to the selected location. Error: 0x80300001".

I figured that this new drive may need partitioning and/or formatting, but I've attempted it via the command prompt only to be presented with yet another error - an I/O error. My hands are essentially firmly tied behind my back now.  I feel like I'm just opening up a long line of Pandora's boxes at every turn!!

This time around, I was confident that, with a fresh batch of official HP Recovery disks, it would be plain sailing - how wrong!

Please can anyone rescue me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 0x80300001 usually points to a faulty controller (or driver for the controller).

Judging by this error, and your [other](https://superuser.com/questions/1014846/windows-8-install-problems-on-a-desktop-pc) [posts](https://superuser.com/questions/1014832/sata-hard-drive-issues), your HDD or the controller is faulty. New drives can be faulty, so try another (known-good) drive, and if it fails, try a different SATA cable, and if it still fails, it's probably a faulty disk controller (or wrong controller driver).

Unless you're using a RAID card or another 3rd party SATA drive controller, it's probably not a driver issue (especially since it sees the drive in Windows) and is instead a failing motherboard.

Comment: Okay. Any recommendations for good brands?

Comment: In general we don't do recommendations here. But regardless of that, I'm not sure what you're asking me to recommend...?

Comment: I read yor post to mean that you were suggesting trying another known-good drive, so I wondered whether you could make any brand recommendations. No worries if it's against the forum protocol though.