# Windows 8 install problems on a desktop PC

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, installation

I'm trying to install Windows 8 on a brand new drive and have encountered a few problems.

My error message (as shown in the photo) is: "We couldn't install windows in the location you chose. Please check your media drive. Here's more info about what happened 0x8007045d".

[image]

I have two other similar posts - I figured it may be less daunting to tackle if I split the large problem into individual units.

Comment: Judging by this error, and your other posts, your HDD or the controller is faulty. New drives can be faulty, so try another (known-good) drive, and if it fails, thy a different SATA cable, and if it still fails, it's probably a faulty disk controller.

Answer (score 0):

From the naming, it looks like you tried to install Windows in the "System" Partition - that won't work the way you set it up.

You can only install Windows in the Primary partition (Which is the first one in your list - Check under 'Type')

Comment: have trouble getting it to fit in 450 MB ;)

Comment: Yes Aganju, I tried installing to all 3 partitions. My attempt to install to the Primary partition returned the error "The drive isn't large enough". I would've happily expanded the size of the partition, but there was no option to do so.

Comment: You cannot maker it larger because right behind it is the second partition. You can either declare another partition the 'Primary', or - if you don't need what is in either partition, - delete them all, and then install windows [understand that you would lose all current content and data permanently!]. Windows installer would then create partitions as needed.

Comment: I would appreciate some tips on how to delete the partitions. I tried directly from the screen above but no joy.  I imagine I need to use DISKPART, but I'm not having much luck due to the I/O error.

Comment: understood, but sorry, i have no better idea right now than the buttons on your screen. You should be able to select the first and second partition, and delete them with the Delete button. Then just select the one big 'unallocated' chunk for the install; Windows will make its necessary partitions it self.

Answer (score 0):

The error code  `0x8007045d` means `ERROR_IO_DEVICE` :

> The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error

Your HDD has some issues. Run a Linux Live DVD and run [SMART tools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) to check if the HDD is damaged.